# Bundling local JavaFX library files into jar using Gradle with Java 8

Tags: java, gradle, javafx, jar

I have a JavaFX application that was written with the Oracle Java 8 JDK. This JDK also includes the JavaFX library natively. To make the application as portable and work on as many JVMs as possible, I introduced Gradle to the project to help automate builds and download JavaFX dependencies for JDKs greater than 8 (because they don't include JavaFX).

So far, by using the [OpenJFX Gradle plugin](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-gradle-plugin), alongside the [Shadow Gradle plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow), I've been able to build and create a fat jar when building using JDKs 11, 12, and 13. These work perfectly as standalone jar files. My main objective here is to be able to package the JavaFX dependencies within the jar itself so that it can be run as a standalone jar file for as many JDKs as possible.

My main problem here is that the OpenJFX Gradle plugin only works with Java versions >= 11. So I can only conditionally use the OpenJFX plugin. This is fine, and the gradle script still works with JDK 8 (as long as the JDK inclues JavaFX). What doesn't work, however, is creating a portable jar file that includes JavaFX as a dependency when running `./gradlew shadowBuild` with Java 8. The jar file is created, but it doesn't add the JavaFX libraries, presumably because Shadow doesn't see this as an external dependency.

The end result is that when I compile using Java 8, and then try and run the jar file using Java 13, I get the following exception: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application`. Conversely, when I compile with Java 11, and then run the jar with Java 11, 12, or 13, it works perfectly.

I've tried manually adding JavaFX as a dependency within the Gradle script, to no avail.

Here are the relevant parts of the build script:

```
if (JavaVersion.current().isJava11Compatible() ||
    JavaVersion.current().isJava12Compatible() ||
    JavaVersion.current() == JavaVersion.VERSION_HIGHER) {
        apply plugin: 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin'

        javafx {
            // javafx modules that are being used by app.
            modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.base', 'javafx.graphics', 'javafx.fxml', 'javafx.swing']
        } 
        // all of these are necessary to use javax library which is no longer included in > java 8
        dependencies {
            compile('javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0')
            compile('javax.activation:activation:1.1')
            compile('org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.0')
         }
    }

shadowJar {
    baseName = 'myJfxApp'
    classifier = null
    version = null
}
```

And here is what is contained within the fat jar that actually *does* contain the external dependencies (as opposed to the one compiled by Java 8):

- javafx
- javafx-swt.jar
- javafx.properties
- javax
- libdecora_sse.dylib
- libglass.dylib
- libjavafx_font.dylib
- libjavafx_iio.dylib
- libprism_common.dylib
- libprism_es2.dylib
- libprism_sw.dylib
- module-info.class
- org

Any ideas on how to include JavaFX libraries that already exist within the Java 8 JDK on my machine (or even from the maven repository) within the created fat jar?

Comment: It is still work in progress but this [branch](https://github.com/jperedadnr/javafx-gradle-plugin/tree/Java8) contains a version of the JavaFX gradle plugin compatible with Java 8. Maybe you can give it a try? Clone, install (`./gradlew clean publishToMavenLocal`), and use the `0.0.9-SNAPSHOT` adding `mavenLocal()` repository to the plugin?

Comment: Cloned the repo and tried running `./gradlew clean publishToMavenLocal`, but got `Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not target platform: 'Java SE 11' using tool chain: 'JDK 8 (1.8)'.` Do I need to run this command using Java 11?

Comment: You can actually build the plugin with any JDK. Are you sure you are building the Java8 branch?

Comment: Yes, you were right, I was in the wrong branch. Using the plugin still works with 11, 12, and 13, but it doesn't seem to be grabbing the dependencies for JDK 8 still.

Comment: Why do you need to "grab the (JavaFX) dependencies"? There is no need for that, if you run against Oracle JDK 8. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @JoséPereda tested using adoptopenjdk-8.jdk (which doesn't have Java FX)

Comment: My main desire here was to automatically package javafx dependencies into the fat jar created by shadow. The javafx plugin while compiled on 8 doesn't actually seem to manage the dependencies if JavaFX isn't present. Is this behavior intended?

Comment: If I get it right, you want to grab OpenJFX 8 and add it as dependencies to your project/jar in the same way as it can be done now with OpenJFX 11? That is not going to work. You will need to install it to your JDK (something like [this](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-build/issues/577#issuecomment-518713653)).