# Multiple service files conflict in openjfx javafxplugin jar creation

Tags: java, gradle, javafx, jax-rs, resteasy

Continuation of [Which ReastEasy 4 client dependencies are needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64115996/which-reasteasy-4-client-dependencies-are-needed)

`build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin'
    id 'java'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 14
targetCompatibility = 14

ext.resteasyVersion = "4.5.8.Final";

dependencies {
    compile "org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-client:$resteasyVersion"
    compile "org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jackson2-provider:$resteasyVersion"
}
```

After executing the `jar` task and running the jar, an error is thrown when trying to create JAX-RS requests:

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY003215: could not find writer for content-type application/json type: java.lang.String
```

This was deemed to be the result of conflicts of service files, resulting in only 1 being packaged. When using the ShadowJar plugin, the solution is to configure it with

```
shadowJar {
  mergeServiceFiles()
}
```

(see [MessageBodyWriter not found error for Jersy / Jetty server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53751401/messagebodywriter-not-found-error-for-jersy-jetty-server)), but this does not work for this plugin's jar generation.

How to resolve this conflict?

Comment: There's a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58330729/2587435) that says it's using the two plugins alongside each other. They didn't state anything about the service files, but have you tried yet to use both of them together?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha Not yet. I want to see if there's a solution without the additional plugin first.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha I checked, ShadowJar doesn't work with JavaFX>8 because of conflict with the modules. It's possible to bundle everything except JavaFX this way, and then use external JavaFX dependencies in runtime. Not ideal.